# Gap between horizontal image and embed video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

There is a gap between the image and embedded video.There is no problem in mobile view.

```html
<div class="section"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> 

        <img  class="embed-responsive-item" width="600px" height="360" src="images\phone.jpg"/>                                  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="560" height="315" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_k4SA"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class 'nopadding' with col-sm-6 ... That will solve your problem.

```
<div class="section"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding"><div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> 

        <img  class="embed-responsive-item" width="600px" height="360" src="images\lenovok5.jpg"/>                                  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="560" height="315" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_9G7CGbk4SA"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS file add following code :

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```